# YouTube HTML5 parameter low quality poster image

Tags: html, iframe, parameters, youtube

i've noticed when using the HTML5 parameter on iframe embedded youtube videos, after the video plays, youtube poster image displays a low quality version instead of the high quality. Anyway to fix this?